# Existence of Continuous Function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The following question requires the use of an easy theorem of calculus, but I am failing to see which one.

Let $ g $ be non-constant and $ C^{1} $ on some interval $ I $. Show that for some subinterval $ J \subseteq I $, there exists a continuous function $ f $ such that the differential equation $ y' = f(y) $ has the solution $ y = g(x) $ on $ J $.

Comment: Don't you mean $y = g(x)$?

Comment: Sorry! Mistake in notation! Corrected.

Comment: Isn't this just the fundamental theorem of calculus, in that differentiation and integration are loosely "inverse" operations? Since $g$ is $C^1$ we can always try $f(x)=g'(x)$ and $f$ will be continuous.

Comment: @Stefan: Did you actually mean ‘$ y'(x) = f(x) $’ instead of ‘$ y'(x) = f(y(x)) $’?

Comment: I am not really sure. I typed the problem as I have it in front of me.

Comment: @Stefan: I tried to solve the problem as it is currently stated. The solution is definitely not a one-step process, but the techniques used are entirely elementary.

Comment: @Stefan: I hope you won’t mind if I re-stated your problem in more precise terms. I haven’t altered the content.

Answer (score 1):

- Suppose that $ g: I \to \mathbb{R} $ is non-constant and $ g \in {C^{1}}(I) $.
- Observe that $ g': I \to \mathbb{R} $ cannot be identically $ 0 $ on $ I $, otherwise by the Mean-Value Theorem, $ g $ would be a constant function.
- Hence, there exists an $ x_{0} \in I $ such that $ g'(x_{0}) \neq 0 $. Without loss of generality, let us assume that $ g'(x_{0}) > 0 $.
- As $ g' $ is continuous on $ I $, there exists an open subinterval $ J $ of $ I $ such that $ x_{0} \in J $ and $ g' > 0 $ on $ J $. Intuitively speaking, as $ g'(x_{0}) > 0 $, the continuity of $ g' $ ensures that $ g'(x) > 0 $ for all points $ x \in I $ that are near $ x_{0} $.
- By the Mean-Value Theorem, $ g|_{J} $ must be strictly increasing.
- Hence, $ (g|_{J})^{-1}: g[J] \to J $ exists and is continuous on $ g[J] $, which is an open interval.
- We now need to find a continuous $ f: g[J] \to \mathbb{R} $ such that
  $$
  \forall x \in J: \quad g'(x) = f(g(x)).
  $$
- If such an $ f $ exists, then it is necessary that
  $$
  \forall x \in g[J]: \quad g'({(g|_{J})^{-1}}(x)) = f(g({(g|_{J})^{-1}}(x))) = f(x).
  $$
- This implies that $ f = g' \circ (g|_{J})^{-1} $, which is continuous on $ g[J] $ because it is the composition of two continuous functions.
- A quick check shows that $ f $ as defined does satisfy the requirements.